# Vfs shipping label not received

Tags: visas, uk, applications, vfs-global

Hi I applied for a UK Visa and bought the return shipping label from VFS. BUT I did not receive a email with label attached after I made the payment. "Download shipping label" button on their sites also didn't work. Does anyone has same issue and resolve it? Can I buy a new return label from UPS store and just use that one?

Many appreciation!

Comment: Have you contacted the VFS Centre through which you applied? Most have a FAQ advising what to do when you don't receive it (a  PDF file or UPS AWB) even though the payment was processed. Yes, I'm sure you can go to a UPS store and buy one, but why would you, when you've paid quite a bit for the premium service?

Comment: If you are applying in the USA, you can buy your own label, but it cannot be a ground shipping service, it must be air (e.g. UPS 2nd day or next day or FedEx 2 day or overnight).

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.